# Survival probability of a biased random walker

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, random-walk

> A random walker moves to $+1$ with probability $p$ and moves to $-1$ with probability $q=1-p$. If he starts at point $m$, what is the probability that he doesn't hit the point zero after $k$ steps, asymptotically for large $k$ and $m$?

I have found results for the case $p=q=1/2$ for brownian motion in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model). The survival probability, the probability that the particle has remained at a position $x < x_c$ for all times up to $t$, is given by

$$ S(t)=\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x_c}{2\sqrt{D t}}\right)$$

How can I convert it to the case that $p\neq 1/2$?

Comment: Hint: Look for "Random walk in Random environment" in dimension 1. There is a connection with the random walk in the random conductance model. Ref: Sznitman

Comment: @Salsifis Huh? No random environment here, and really no need to appeal to random conductances models.

Comment: Hint: The first hitting time $T_m$ of $0$ starting at $m$ is the sum of $m$ i.i.d. random variables distributed like $T_1$ the first hitting time of $0$ starting at $1$. Now, $T_1=1$ with probability $q$ and $T_1=1+S$ with probability $p$ where $S$ is distributed like $T_2$. Thus, $u(s)=E(s^{T_1})$ solves $u(s)=s(q+pu(s)^2)$, that is, $$u(s)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pqs^2}}{2s}.$$ Asymptotics on the tail of $T_1$, then on the tail of every $T_m$, follow from this explicit formula, for example, when $n\to\infty$, $$\frac1n\log P(T_1=2n+1)\to\log(4pq).$$